# ons-carousel-itemをng-repeatで作成した場合にinitial-indexが効かない

Tags: onsen-ui, angularjs

ons-carouselのons-carousel-itemをng-repeatを使って作成しているのですが、
initial-indexがどうも効いていないようで、1つ目のアイテムが表示されてしまいます。
どうすればinitial-indexが反映されるようになるのでしょうか？

コードは以下のような感じです。
前のページからファイルの情報や絞り込みのフィルタ等を含んだdataを渡しています。

```
<ons-carousel fullscreen swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll var="carousel" initial-index="{{data.index}}">
    <ons-carousel-item ng-repeat="filedata in data.files | filter:data.filetype | filter:data.searchtext">
        <div class="center">{{filedata.filename}}</div>
        <img src="{{filedata.filepath}}" class="carouselimg" width="100%">
    </ons-carousel-item>
</ons-carousel>
```

Comment: 現象が再現できるコードを載せましょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。試してみます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おそらく`ons-carousel-item`で`ng-repeat`を使用しているので、`ons-carousel`で`initial-index`を指定してもその時点では`ons-carousel-item`は一つも存在せず、反映されないのではないかと思われます。

コントローラを使用しているのであれば、`setActiveCarouselItemIndex`メソッドで指定できます。

```
ons.ready(function() {
    carousel.setActiveCarouselItemIndex($scope.data.index);
});
```